Moving points along a sphere is not causing distortion when projected onto a equirectangular map
I'm trying to get points from an image, project them onto a sphere, move the points along the sphere, and then convert them back for simulating plate tectonics. The code to get the points from the image works fine, it's the functions relating to moving the points that aren't working. I'm expecting polar distortion, but the shape is mostly just being translated.
def __detect_shapes(image):
    img = Image.open(image)
    
    img = img.convert("L")
    img = img.point(lambda p: p > 128 and 255)
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    
    # get a list of every black pixel
    black_pixels = []
    
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            if img.getpixel((x, y)) == (0, 0, 0):
                black_pixels.append((x, y))

    # separate the black pixels into shapes
    black_pixels = set(black_pixels)
    shapes = []
    
    while black_pixels:
        shape = []
        stack = [black_pixels.pop()]
        
        while stack:
            x, y = stack.pop()
            shape.append((x, y))
            for dx in range(-1, 2):
                for dy in range(-1, 2):
                    if (dx, dy) == (0, 0):
                        continue
                    
                    neighbor = (x + dx, y + dy)
                    
                    if neighbor in black_pixels:
                        stack.append(neighbor)
                        black_pixels.remove(neighbor)
                        
        shapes.append(shape)
    
    return shapes

def __move_point(point, width, height, dx, dy):
    lambda_0 = width / 2
    phi_1 = height / 2
    
    map_point = __convert_to_map_space(point, width, height)
    spherical_point = __convert_to_spherical(map_point, lambda_0, phi_1)
    new_point = __rotate_point(spherical_point, dx, -dy)
    equirectangular_point = __convert_to_equirectangular(new_point, lambda_0, phi_1)
    x, y = __convert_to_image_space(equirectangular_point, width, height)
    
    return (int(x), int(y))

def __convert_to_map_space(point, width, height, map_width=360, map_height=180):
    x, y = point
    
    _x = (x / width) * map_width - (map_width / 2)
    _y = (y / height) * map_height - (map_height / 2)
    
    return (_x, _y)

def __convert_to_spherical(point, lambda_0, phi_1):
    x, y = point # point is in degrees
    
    x = np.deg2rad(x)
    y = np.deg2rad(y)
    
    cos_phi_1 = np.cos(np.deg2rad(phi_1))
    lambda_0 = np.deg2rad(lambda_0)
    
    r = 1
    _lambda = (x / cos_phi_1) + lambda_0
    _phi = y
    
    return (r, _phi, _lambda)

# dtheta and dphi are in DREGREES
def __rotate_point(point, dphi, dtheta):
    r, theta, phi = point # point is in radians
    
    phi += np.deg2rad(dphi)
    theta += np.deg2rad(dtheta)
    
    return (r, theta, phi)

def __convert_to_equirectangular(point, lambda_0, phi_1):
    _, _phi, _lambda = point # point is in radians
    
    lambda_0 = np.deg2rad(lambda_0)
    
    x = (_lambda - lambda_0) * np.cos(phi_1)
    y = _phi
    
    return (x, y)

def __convert_to_image_space(point, width, height, map_width=360, map_height=180):
    _x, _y = point # point is in radians
    
    _x = np.rad2deg(_x)
    _y = np.rad2deg(_y)
    
    x = _x + (map_width / 2) # recenter
    x = (x / map_width) * width # scale
    
    y = _y + (map_height / 2)
    y = (y / map_height) * height
    
    return (x, y)

output = Image.new("RGB", (512, 256), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output)

shapes = __detect_shapes("import/test.png")

for s in shapes:
    for p in s:
        draw.point(p, fill="black")

for p in shapes[1]:
    moved_point = __move_point(p, 512, 256, -50, 90)
    draw.point(moved_point, fill="red")

output.save("export/test.png")
output.show()

Here's the test image:
Three black shapes

Here's the result after running the program:
same three black shapes, but the rightmost one has been moved up

And here's what I (roughly) would have expected to happen:
Same three black shapes, but the right most one has been moved up and been distorted

Why is there no distortion in the result of the program?

There is no trigonometry anywhere in your code. Your __convert_to_spherical is just translating and scaling your rectangular coordinates, and not converting to spherical coordinates

With the projection you use, I wouldn't expect any distortion - for any ΔLat and ΔLong defining a shape, the same ΔLat will become the same Δy, and the same ΔLong becomes the same Δx, while ΔLat and ΔLong are obviously preserved through rotation.

I was wrong to think that your projection is not equirectangular; there is a cos(Latitude1) multiplicative term in Δx, but Latitude1 = 0 for the canonical equirectangular projection mathworld link.

@kikon you're right, I updated the code

The answer was to not use polar coordinates and instead use a rotation matrix with the Cartesian Coordinates. Here's the finalized code.
# np -> numpy

# simple point class
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def get_array(self):
        return np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z])

# we store values to avoid calculating them hundreds of time
class MapStruct():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width # in pixels
        self.height = height
        # the width of the image is the circumference of the sphere 
        # we use that sphere's radius for the math and not the earth's
        # also, because the image is equirectangular (width = 2 * height)
        # we can just use the height for the equation
        self.radius = height / np.pi
        self.prime_meridian = width // 2
        self.equator = height // 2
        self.scaling_factor = width / 360.0

# automatically calculates the Cartesian point from the image point and map values
def construct_point(map_struct : MapStruct, _x : int, _y : int) -> Point:
    # setting the middle of the image to the origin. Because the image from 
    # PIL.Image.Open() is read in from the top left, we flip the y-axis to 
    # make the math easier
    x_, y_ = _x - map_struct.prime_meridian, map_struct.equator - _y
    
    # we store lat and long as radians so we don't have to convert them later
    long = np.deg2rad(x_ / map_struct.scaling_factor)
    lat = np.deg2rad(y_ / map_struct.scaling_factor)
    
    # converting lat and longitude to Cartesian
    x = map_struct.radius * np.cos(lat) * np.cos(long)
    y = map_struct.radius * np.cos(lat) * np.sin(long)
    z = map_struct.radius * np.sin(lat)
    
    return Point(x, y, z)

# convert Cartesian coordinates back into image points (with the origin at the
# top left, not in the middle)
def get_image_coordinates(point : Point, map_struct : MapStruct) -> tuple:
    lat = np.arcsin(point.z / map_struct.radius)
    long = np.arctan2(point.y, point.x)
    
    # lat and long will be in radians, so we convert them back to degrees
    # before converting them back to pixels (for a 1024 x 512 image, that 
    # ~2.84 pixels per degree)
    x = (np.rad2deg(long) * map_struct.scaling_factor) + map_struct.prime_meridian
    y = map_struct.equator - (np.rad2deg(lat) * map_struct.scaling_factor)
    
    return (x, y)
       
# we expect distance in degrees
def move_point(point : Point, vector : tuple, distance : float) -> Point:
    # from here on, its standard rotation matrix stuff.
    dir_vector = _normalize(vector)
    axis = _normalize(np.cross(point.get_array(), dir_vector))
    theta = np.deg2rad(distance)
    
    R = _rotation_matrix(axis, theta)
    
    return Point(*np.dot(R, point.get_array()))

def _normalize(vector : tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    x, y, z = vector
    v = np.array([x, y, z])
    return v / np.linalg.norm(v)

def _rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    a = np.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * np.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a*a, b*b, c*c, d*d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b*c, a*d, a*c, a*b, b*d, c*d
    return np.array([[aa+bb-cc-dd, 2*(bc+ad), 2*(bd-ac)],
                     [2*(bc-ad), aa+cc-bb-dd, 2*(cd+ab)],
                     [2*(bd+ac), 2*(cd-ab), aa+dd-bb-cc]])

And replacing the __move_point function with this one:
# distance is in degrees
def move(point, vector, distance, map_struct):
    p = construct_point(map_struct, point[0], point[1])
    new_p = move_point(p, vector, distance)
    return get_image_coordinates(new_p, map_struct)

output = Image.new("RGB", (1024, 512), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output)

shapes = __detect_shapes("import/test.png") # defined in the question above

for s in shapes:
    for p in s:
        draw.point(p, fill="black")

ms = MapStruct(1024, 512)

for p in shapes[1]:
    moved_point = move(
        p,
        (13, 9, -32),
        35,
        ms
    )
    draw.point(moved_point, fill="red")

output.save("export/test.png")
output.show()


returns this image:

